# What time does Gulliver wake up?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Occasionally, Gulliver gets stranded on my island. There's a reward for helping him, but you need to wait until he actually wakes up until you can help. If I find Gulliver on my island in the morning, when can I expect to be able to help him?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Gulliver doesn't wake up at a specific time, he wakes up after you've talked to him enough. I haven't kept track of exactly how many times you need to chat with him, but it's usually around 5 attempts, and then he'll finally wake up. In other words, he can wake up as soon as you find him, provided you keep talking to him.

Comment: I actually really hate this mechanic. It's so not obvious that you can keep talking until he wakes up. I missed out on gulliver the first time as well

Comment: @Cruncher: An important video game rule: as long as NPC keeps giving you new responses you keep clicking on 'em

Comment: @Maxim It could have just been pulling responses out of a decently sized random pool though, which is what I thought was happening. But fair enough, that's a good rule of thumb